# Cocos2d-x unresolved external symbol 'ccNextPOT'

Tags: visual-c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-win32

Build **Cocos2d-x v3.4** game for **Win32** in Visual Studio 2013.
After adding call of **ccNextPOT** method

```
// test call
int w = cocos2d::ccNextPOT(300);
```

got next error

```
1>HelloWorldScene.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cocos2d::ccNextPOT(int)" (?ccNextPOT@cocos2d@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall HelloWorld::init(void)" (?init@HelloWorld@@UAE_NXZ)
1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\TestGame\proj.win32\Debug.win32\TestGame.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Error appears for Debug and Release builds. Without this call project is builded fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add `CC_DLL` to function definition in **ccUtils.h**. It makes function visible in **libcocos2d.dll** library. It should have the next look:

```
int CC_DLL ccNextPOT(int value);
```